# How to get all rows from myslq table by foreach loop in php pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to collect all rows from a table of mySql database. But I am getting 1 row lesser than the original rows. Suppose the table has 3 rows but I am getting data of 2 rows. I am missing the first one always. Here is the image of my table.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `POS_refund`");

if($query->fetchColumn() > 0){

     foreach($query as $row){

        echo $get_prod_id = $row['prod_id'];

        $get_prod_qnt = $row['qnt'];

    } 

}
```

Where is the fault?

Comment: What do you mean by "missing the first one" ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php - *"PDOStatement::fetchColumn() should not be used to retrieve boolean columns, as it is impossible to distinguish a value of FALSE from there being no more rows to retrieve. Use PDOStatement::fetch() instead."*

Comment: I am not getting the first row. It is only fetching the last two rows. @executable

Comment: Why not just do http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php? Also not clear what you're doing with `echo $get_prod_id = $row['prod_id'];` and the next assignment. Your `$get_prod_qnt` will only have the last value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PDOStatement::fetchColumn` Returns a **single** column from the next row of a result set

You should use `fetch()` or `fetchall()` in your case

```
<?php

$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `POS_refund`")->fetchall();

foreach($query as $row){

    echo $get_prod_id = $row['prod_id'];

    $get_prod_qnt = $row['qnt'];

} 
?>
```

If you want to see if there's records returned you could use `count()` since `fetchall()` returns array, then just count your array elemenets

```
<?php

$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `POS_refund`");
$results = $query->fetchall();

if(count($results) > 0){
     foreach($results as $row){

        echo $get_prod_id = $row['prod_id'];

        $get_prod_qnt = $row['qnt'];

    } 

}else{

    echo "No results";
}

?>
```

Comment: `$get_prod_qnt = $row['qnt'];` - that also needs to be echo'd, unless they don't want to that is; heh.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner yes it should be, provided that Op wanna display it as well

Comment: But how to check whether there is a row or not in this query? @MasivuyeCokile

Answer (score -1):

I would use a while loop. it would look like this:

```
while ($row = $query->fetchall) {
    echo $get_prod_id = $row['prod_id'];

    $get_prod_qnt = $row['qnt'];
}
```